# Asp.net MVC 2.0 DataAnnotations Validation doesn't emit correct JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-validate, data-annotations

I'm trying to get setup using the DataAnnotations validator in ASP.Net MVC 2.0 Beta, but with the following model:

```
public class Foo {
    [Required] public string Bar {get;set;} 
}
```

And the following code in my view:

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Foo>" %>

 <!-- later on -->
 <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("Edit","Foo")) { %>
```

Everything is almost verbatim form the examples. What is emitted is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
EnableClientValidation({"Fields":[],"FormId":"form0"}, null);
//]]>
</script>
```

Nothing is ever emitted to tell whatever JavaScript validation library (jQuery or MS Ajax, doesn't matter) to validate the fields. The validation *does* happen on the server side, but never on the client, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Note: I'm trying to use the jQuery validation adapter. Using the MS Ajax one still yields 

Sys.Mvc.FormValidation.enableClientValidation({"Fields":[],"FormId":"form0"}, null);

Nothing about the required property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a bit sneaky. I [found out](http://hadihariri.com/blogengine/post/2009/10/08/The-Principle-of-Least-Surprise.aspx) the problem is the lack of `ValidationMessageFor` even though there is a `ValidationSummary`. After adding the following:

```
<%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Bar)%>
```

The proper JSON was emitted and the jQuery validation worked.

It seems odd you *have* to have the message even though you have the validation summary.

Comment: Use Html.Validate() or Html.ValidateFor() if you want validation but don't want a message span.